# I want to get a description for a image in a state in my react application using OpenAI vision API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openai-api

i have developed a react application, basically like a googl form that accepts images and records audio, use location etc.

I have single resoponse state that saves the image when then user uploads an image from their phone. what I'm trying to do is to use that image and send it to vision API and get a response.

so I have created a functions for:

1. converting the image from the state to a base64imagee.
2. sending that converted image to vision api and get a response.

i tried these and the errors that im getting.

this is the code that I used for analysing image.

`    async function analyzeImage(base64Image) {
const payload = {
model: "gpt-4-vision-preview",
messages: [
{
role: "user",
content: "What’s in this image?",
},
{
role: "system",
content: {
"image": {
"data": base64Image,
},
},
},
],
};

```
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`
    };
  
    try {

    const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        // Here you can handle the response, e.g., update the state or display the analysis results
      } else {
        console.error('Server responded with an error:', response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to send request:', error);
    }
  }
```

`

and this is the code that i used for converting my image to a base64image using the photo uploaded to a state.

`    const handleImageChange = (event) => {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
const file = event.target.files[0];

```
        // Update the state with the selected file
        setResponses({ ...responses, photo: file });

        // Convert the image file to a Base64 string
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const base64Image = reader.result.replace('data:', '').replace(/^.+,/, '');

            // Here you can either update the state with the Base64 string or
            // call a function to handle the next steps, like sending it to your server.
            // For example, you could update your state (not shown here due to potential re-renders and large data sizes)
            // Or directly call a function like this:
            // analyzeImage(base64String);
            analyzeImage(base64Image);

            // If you choose to update the state, it might look something like this:
            // setResponses({ ...responses, photoBase64: base64String });

            // Note: Storing large Base64 strings in the state can lead to performance issues.
            // It's generally better to handle the string directly without storing it in the state if possible.
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
};`
```

The error that im getting from the console is,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA53k.png)